# RuntimeError: all only supports torch.uint8 and torch.bool dtypes

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to write an assertion statement in my code. The goal of the assertion statement is to check for data leakage, hence I don't want to just delete it.

```py
assert filled_target[:, -forecast_length:, :].any() != trg[:, d -forecast_length:decoder_seq_len, :].any()
```

However this is raising the following error

`RuntimeError: all only supports torch.uint8 and torch.bool dtypes`

Both `filled_target` and `trg` are type `torch.cuda.FloatTensor` .  I'm not sure if this is [related to this or not](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/44779).

Comment: Can you try `assert (filled_target[:, -forecast_length:, :].any() != trg[:, d -forecast_length:decoder_seq_len, :].any()).all()` not sure if you want `.all()` or `any()` here.

Comment: That gave me the same error `RuntimeError: all only supports torch.uint8 and torch.bool dtypes`